# Javascript - Accordion: how to let only one item to be open at any given time

Tags: html-framework-7

I want to write a script that allows **only one** item to be *open* at any given time, forcing the *other* to be *closed*.

How can I do that?

This is my starting point:

```
var myApp = new Framework7();

var $$ = Dom7;

$$('.accordion-item').on('opened', function () {
    myApp.alert('Accordion item opened');
});

$$('.accordion-item').on('closed', function (e) {
    myApp.alert('Accordion item closed');
});
```

Comment: What you want to do actually?Can you explain...

Comment: I`m use Angularjs ng-repeat [link](http://paste.ofcode.org/fpwNsBV7ZzxZYeNHU5MKvP)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Framework7 accordion list always have just one open, and the other close.

[Accordion Docs](http://framework7.io/docs/accordion.html)

```
<!-- List View -->
<div class="content-block-title">List View Accordion</div>
      <!-- add "accordion-list" class -->
<div class="list-block accordion-list"> 
  <ul>
    <li class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="item-content item-link">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="item-title">Item 1</div>
        </div></a>
      <div class="accordion-item-content">
        <div class="content-block">
          <p>Item 1 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li class="accordion-item"><a href="#" class="item-content item-link">
        <div class="item-inner">
          <div class="item-title">Item 2</div>
        </div></a>
      <div class="accordion-item-content">
        <div class="content-block">
          <p>Item 2 content. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    ...
  </ul>
</div>
```